# how to find format of pack() -ed binary data and unpack it

Tags: php, binary, format, pack, unpack

I have stored binary data in Mysql field like this: `0x31` and `0x31303030303332` . this was converted to binary data from string, I don't know that string and I don't know how string had converted to this binary data.
As far as I know the `pack()` and `unpack()` PHP functions can help me, BUT I can't convert back this binary data to string because I don't know what format (second argument of `unpack()` function) had been used. 
How can I find correct format to add in `unpack('format', $mybinarystring)` function?
Or may be this can be converted back via another function or method?

Comment: Looks like the number 1000032, converted to string and encoded as binary to me.

Comment: so there is no any way to find a way to convert back this binary data?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to definitely find out which format is used to create the binary data, because its just binary data. You can guess, look at the content and find a hint, or just try&error.